# How can I make a responsive horizontal navbar that toggles upon click?

Tags: html, css, web

As a UX Designer, I want to update my portfolio website but I can't find any templates that I like. SO I chose the next best thing and tried to code it. I made my prototype in Figma but I can't seem to make my code work the way that I want it.

[Figma Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqQp9.png)

I want my navbar to be interactive so that it will display the hidden links upon clicking the chevron arrow. There are a few things that I want it to do.

1. Upon clicking, the chevron would disappear, then rotate 180 degrees, then reappear.
2. The navbar height on default will be 75px shorter until clicked.
3. During active state, the navbar will push the content below downwards and pull it back up when it is set back into its default state.

Currently, my HTML looks like this:

```
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar__logo">
                <a class="logo" href="../main/main.html"><img src="../assets/logo.png" width="60px" height="60px"></a>
            </nav>

            <nav class="hiddenMenu">
                <ul class="navList">
                    <li class="hiddenLinks"> <a href="#">About  </a> </li>
                    <li class="hiddenLinks"> <a href="#">Works  </a> </li>
                    <li class="hiddenLinks"> <a href="#">Resume </a> </li>
                    <li class="hiddenLinks"> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav class="chevron">
                    <a class="down" href="#"><img src="../assets/chevrondown.png" width="30px" height="12px"></a>
            </nav>


        </header>
```

My CSS looks like it's all over the place so if anyone can help what the best way to code this is, I'd love to hear your suggestions. I've been watching Hambuger Menu tutorial videos as they might be the most similar but their solutions are to move the menu out of the screen which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly more challenging problem to do in all css, but here is a sample.
Use the chevron as a checkbox label, and toggle height of the nav section based on the state of the input, i.e. check or not. I'm also not sure if you had predefined Icons you wanted to use, so I just created the chevron using css pseudo elements.

If you wanted to use icons instead, just select the icon and rotate it when the checkbox is checked. You can use my example here of rotating the pseudo elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
  padding: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

header .chevron {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

header .chevron::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: black;
    transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

header .chevron::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 42%;
  background-color: black;
    transition: transform 400ms ease;
}


header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 300ms ease;
}

header nav a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ nav {
  height: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .chevron::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .chevron::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- Logo -->
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <!-- Menu Toggle -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle" hidden />
  <!-- Popout Nav -->
  <nav>
    <a>About</a>
    <a>Works</a>
    <a>Resume</a>
    <a>Contact</a>
  </nav>
  <!-- Menu Label -->
  <label class="chevron" for="menuToggle">
  </label>
</header>
```